# scrollIntoView on element with height = 0 in angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have the following html:

```
<div class="row-20 st-margin" *ngIf="role == 'Administrator'" id="hr-data">
  <div class="col-md-12"></div>
</div>
```

and after ajax call I have that `div` visible.
Then I want to scroll to that `div` by click:

```
document.getElementById('hr-data').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

but it doesn't work.

So, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, `div class="row-20 st-margin"` has no height.
I moved `id` to `div class="col-md-12"` and it works fine:

```
<div class="row-20 st-margin" *ngIf="role == 'Administrator'">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="hr-data"></div>
</div>
```